# What is wrong with my code? I am trying to launch phaser game, but its not working

Tags: google-chrome, canvas, html5-canvas, phaser-framework

I am trying to launch game locally, but i have some problems.
Sources seems to be ok , down from github.
Here is one of these mistakes.

Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: Ah the dreaded CORS.  It seems strange that you would be getting cross origin request when running locally.  Are you pulling phaser (or any other dependencies) from the interwebs?  Can you post your Script tags?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, thanks for the link to GitHub, I pulled the game down and reproduced the error.  It seems strange to me that you wouldn't be able to get .gifs and .wavs when running locally, but there are legitimate security concerns with cross orgin requests, which is why most browsers are so locked down.

Luckily, there is a fairly simple solution to this problem, which I was able to confirm, at least on my end.  It does involve running a server, but fortunately the basic Python library provides us with a very easy way to do run a local server.  If you already have Python installed, you're ready to go, otherwise, go here: https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/

With python installed, its as easy as navigating to the folder containing your index.html file (like FlappyZozio-master) in your command prompt, and typing the following command:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Then you can access your game at the url: localhost:8000

There are other ways to set up local servers, as QUIPHOP mentioned, there's node for example.  But I find Python to be easiest for quick testing purposes.

Comment: thx 
i already have openserver
ctrl+C ctrl+v
and now seems to be ok.Games are working.
TNX

Comment: @EdwardRyzhewski you should still mark bradimus' answer as the solution of your problem

Comment: @SUBHUMAN I concur with this assessment :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like You haven't installed your game on the server. This is required for Phaser

Comment: ok, i am new to phaser.If i have downloaded all sources, what should i do to install game?

Comment: Install locally any server You like(e.g nodejs, LAMP, python+flask or somethin') and move your sources(js, html page, css etc.) here. Then work with your game on server. For example : http://www.tips4design.com/2015/06/js-running-phaser-in-nodejs.html

Comment: @QUIPHOP - it sounds like he is trying to run his game locally, which wouldn't involve a server at all.  Edward, could you clarify where you're trying to run your game, and what dependencies it has?

Comment: i ve downloaded sources and trying to run index.html.Thats all.

Comment: What sources?  Whats in index.html?
For example, here's script tags from an old game of mine:
    <script src="js/phaser-1-5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/justpressed.js"></script>
How are you trying to import your source files?

Comment: game sources:index.html, phaser.js, assets, sprites, other js files like boot.js, game.js